# Show data from 2 columns in one

Tags: sql-server, html-table

I have a table (id, short description, extended description, image), and I want to show both the short and the extended description in one column.

[image: Example here]

Comment: Have you tried `ShortDescription + ' ' + LongDescription as NewDescription`?

Comment: Hi Dale, Yes, but I want to show both descriptions on different lines as the picture shows

Comment: Instead of a space add a line break? I'm sure you manage the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONCAT` function and `CHAR(13)` to attain this requirement:

```
SELECT S.ID, CONCAT(S.Short_Description, '<-- Short 
Desc,', CHAR(13), S.Extended_Description, '<-- Extended Desc'), S.Image
FROM Table S
```

Comment: I used CONCAT and CHAR(13) but It show all in one line again

Comment: Can u check from your front end .I think it should be reflected only from the front end itself @MiguelMatos

Comment: I used the example from this page: [link] (https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/inserting-line-break-or-carriage-return-or-tab) and again all is showed in one line.. Maybe i have to enable/disable some options in my MS SQL v18.4?